# Some video tutorials for running.

Tags: running

I used to go to the gym when I was younger, but I have no training or workouts for about 8 years.

I have put on weight, but I want to start again. I love running, but I am afraid I might do something wrong, like over-running, or something like that.

So does anyone know any guide, tutorial on running? And video would be much better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Ako! I suggest you edit your question somewhat, because rather than asking for 'some video', try to specify what you think you're doing wrong and where you need help with. [Have a look at this blog post to get an idea on how to get better answers](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Ivo in that we need some more information before we can properly answer. That said some specifics that would help us help you:

How much weight is "some"? Or if you don't want to say precisely (which I thoroughly understand), how overweight are you on a scale of 1-10 where 10 is "Have you seen The Biggest Loser?" and 1 is "no seriously, I've got about 5-10 pounds extra."

This is important in the running game. If you are above a 5 on that scale I would start with walking and some non-impact cardio before running, maybe some swimming. Once you felt comfortable (rough guess 3-6 weeks depending on the position, higher on the 1-10 scale above means longer) move to some jogging. I'd go with short bursts with rest periods - say 50-70% of your ability for a few minutes followed by an equal rest time and do this for half an hour. From there feel free to try any number of running programs till you find something you enjoy.

This leads to the second important detail: why? what is your goal? Do you want to do a 5k? Consider the Couch to 5k program. Marathon? Just to lose some weight or get healthier? That determines what you will want to progress to once you've got a baseline capability restored.

Cheers

Comment: For overweight I think I am 7! And I really want to lose weight, and get healthier.